# node.js simple web server request life cycle

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to server side Javascript so to Node.js. Well, Here I'm trying some very simple thing such as

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log("node server");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(2424);
```

As I see the result whenever I send a request to the server `console.log("node server");` executes twice. Why it's happening, how node (or `http.createServer`) serves a request?

Comment: Well, log the request. It's probable one of them is for the favicon if you call your server from a browser.

Comment: @dystroy both of the time if (request.path != '/favicon') is true

Comment: Log the request, don't make a test like this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, all requests to pages also asks for the favicon.

To check what resources are being requested on a single page visit, try the additional console.log.

```
console.log(request.path);
```

Just a hunch, but this is probably the most likely cause.

Comment: both of the time `if (request.path != '/favicon')` is true

Comment: apologies, I modified my answer a bit in the event I misremembered the path being called.  Can you try logging request.path and see what it produces?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your request code when you post request.